# How to Implement Wait function in windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to connect to a server using Ip address from client. To get the Ip address of server I am using below code, It detecting the server correctly but I want to perform some other function after `HostEndPoint` variable set by event handler untill that I need to make wait How can I implement it? .. Below code used to scan is Proper way? If not how?

Thanks

```
int startIp = 0;
int EndIp = 255;
int HostPort = 4678;
string = ipPrefix = "192.168.1.";
EndPoint HostEndPoint;

private void ScanHosts()
        {

           Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        for (startIP = 0; startIP <= endIP; startIP++)
        {
            DnsEndPoint endPoint = new DnsEndPoint(ipPrefix + startIP.ToString(), HostPort);

            try
            {
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                socketEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = endPoint;
                socketEventArgs.UserToken = clientSocket;
                socketEventArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(socketEventArgs_Connected);


                clientSocket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArgs);


            }
            catch { }

        }

    }

private void socketEventArgs_Connected(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                HostEndPoint = e.RemoteEndPoint;                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoResetEvent for it.  FE my usage:

```
 AutoResetEvent autoResetLoadDiscTitleAndPersonalDataById = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                                    DataService.LoadDiscTitleAndPersonalDataById(titleToSync.id_on_server, titleInfoXML =>
                                    {
                                        Title TitleInfo = new Title(titleInfoXML);
                                        TitleInfo.UpdateToDb();
                                        autoResetLoadDiscTitleAndPersonalDataById.Set();
                                    });
                                    autoResetLoadDiscTitleAndPersonalDataById.WaitOne();
```